# find group within Mailchimp List C# code

Tags: c#, mailchimp

how to find group with Mailchimp List using C# code (using MCAPI.NET wrapper library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I researched a lot on the web, however I was not been able to find suitable example for finding group associated with mailchimp list using C#. finally, I do it myself which you may find helpful. Furthermore, I am using MCAPI.NET wrapper library for this code.

```
string apikey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailchimpapikey"];
string listId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ListID"];

var input = new listInterestGroupingsInput(apikey, listId);
var lig = new listInterestGroupings(input);
var success = lig.Execute(input);
```